# unique_ptr and normal pointer doesnt match

Tags: c++

```
int a = 1;

int* w = &a;
std::unique_ptr<int> v(new int(a));

cout << "*w: " << *w << endl;// this works
cout << "*v: " << *v << endl;// this works

cout << "w: " << w << endl; // this works
cout << "v: " << v << endl; // this doesnt work
cout << "v: " << v.get() << endl; // this works
```

I thought unique pointer constructure is just like a normal one.
but when i try getting address of this pointer by raw defined name,  it shows error  on unique_pointer that "no operator matches this operator". it only works by v.get() method

What am i missing?

Comment: A "unique pointer" is a pointer in name only. It has some overloaded operators in order to let you use pointer-like syntax for accessing the object it manages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no overloaded `operator<<` function that takes a `std::unique_ptr` object.

Printing pointers is often useless except in a very few cases (mostly debugging purposes) so there's really no need for a generic `operator<<` overload for the smart pointers.

If you make it a habit to print smart pointers (though I don't understand why), you can easily add your own overload.